# How to insert a placeholder value in empty cells in a 2D character array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to be able to pull text from a file and insert it into a 2D character array and any extra cells need to be populated with an @ character instead. If the text file is too long any characters that do not fit need to be ignored. The code I currently have places text in a 20 row by 45 column character array but only if the text file is exactly 900 bytes.

```js
package myfirstjavaproject;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class temp {
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
  File file = new File ("test.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
  String st = br.readLine();
  
     int row = 20, column = 45;
     int offset = 0;
     char[][] array = new char [row][column];
     
     for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
       array[i][j] = st.charAt(offset++);
       System.out.print(array[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println();
      
     
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: first, create your array, and fill it with '@'s. then overwrite the cells for which you do have a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment mentioned, an easy approach is to first fill your board up with your placeholder and then override only the required places.

Another approach is to use the offset you’ve obtained to iterate the rest of the array, filling it with placeholders.

A 3rd (and arguably better) approach is to use the offset to limit access to the array (if the array is much bigger than the actual file, this will be significantly faster).

edit: I've added my code examples of all 3 approaches

```
package basic;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class temp {
    private static final char PLACEHOLDER = '@';

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "";
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            input = br.readLine();
        }
        int row = 20, column = 45;
        char[][] array = new char[row][column];
        // option 1
        //firstFillWithPlaceholders(input, row, column, array);
        // option 2
        //firstFillWithData(input, row, column, array);
        // print method for options 1 & 2
        //printArray(row, column, array);
        // option 3
        My2DArray<Character> myClass = useOop(input, row, column);
        // print method for option 3
        System.out.println(myClass);
    }

    private static My2DArray<Character> useOop(String input, int row, int column) {
        My2DArray<Character> result = new My2DArray<Character>(row, column, PLACEHOLDER);
        int offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < row && offset < input.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column && offset < input.length(); j++) {
                result.set(i, j, input.charAt(offset++));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void firstFillWithData(String input, int row, int column, char[][] array) {
        int offset = 0;
        offset = writeData(input, row, column, offset, array);
        fillTheRestWithPlaceholders(row, column, offset, array);
    }

    private static void fillTheRestWithPlaceholders(int row, int column, int offset, char[][] array) {
        for (int i = offset / column; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                if (i*column + j >= offset) {
                    array[i][j] = PLACEHOLDER;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void firstFillWithPlaceholders(String input, int row, int column, char[][] array) {
        int offset = 0;
        fillWithPlaceHolders(row, column, array);
        offset = writeData(input, row, column, offset, array);
    }

    private static void fillWithPlaceHolders(int row, int column, char[][] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                array[i][j] = PLACEHOLDER;
            }
        }
    }

    private static int writeData(String input, int row, int column, int offset, char[][] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row && offset < input.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column && offset < input.length(); j++) {
                array[i][j] = input.charAt(offset++);
            }
        }
        return offset;
    }

    private static void printArray(int row, int column, char[][] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

My 3rd option uses a new "class"

```
package basic;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class My2DArray<T> {

    private final int row;
    private final int column;
    private final T placeholder;
    private final boolean[][] isSet;
    private final Map<Integer, T> data;

    public My2DArray(int row, int column, T placeholder) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.placeholder = placeholder;
        isSet = new boolean[row][column];
        data = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void set(int i, int j, T value) {
        if (i < row && i >= 0 && j < column && j >= 0) {
            isSet[i][j] = true;
            data.put(i * column + j, value);
        }
    }

    public T get(int i, int j) {
        if (i < row && i >= 0 && j < column && j >= 0) {
            if (isSet[i][j]) {
                return data.get(i * column + j);
            } else {
                return placeholder;
            }
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                sb.append(get(i, j));
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This may seem like a really low level question but how would I then overwrite the @ values?

Comment: added in the answer